# Widget is placed behind window titlebar, no matter what

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have been using a widget in my tkinter programs, but the problem with this widget is the fact that it shows under the windows titlebar, here is the widget I am using:

```py
class LabeledEntry(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text, width=120, insertion="0"):
        super().__init__(master, width=width)
        self.pack_propagate(False)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=text)

        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self)

        self.label.pack(side='left')
        self.entry.pack(side='right')
```

Apparently, the problem is with the pack propagate function, but I need it so that multiple widgets can look equal on the same column.

EDIT: So, apparently, the problem wasnt the fact that it was "being placed behind the window", but because i had to manually input a height for the frame since it doesnt depend on its children for size. Thanks to the commenter who said that.

By the way, if you were wondering what it looked like without the height, here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb2yD.jpg

Comment: Such a problem would presumably be due to the geometry management you apply to the instance of `LabeledEntry`, which you haven't shown us.  [mcve], please.

Comment: How do you create the instance of `LabeledEntry`? Since you haven't specify the `height` of it, it will be zero because you have executed `self.pack_propagate(False)`.

Comment: Please show a complete [mcve]. I don't see why you think it's placed behind the widnow titlebar. I don't even see how that's possible in tkinter. Since you don't give a height to the frame it's going to be just one pixel tall.